# "He is sat on a bus"

Tags: word-usage, verbs, passive-voice

I have occasionally heard or seen the verb "sit" used in the passive. My initial impression was that it was a typo/error. But I have seen it occur enough to start to doubt that. For instance:

> Shaun **is sat** on a bus crowded with blank passengers. ([source](https://youtu.be/mzqDiSr4jY4?t=249))
>
> On the evening of December 1, 1955, Parks **was sat on a bus** in Alabama, heading home after a long day of work. ([source](https://catalyst.cm/8-people-who-broke-the-law-to-change-the-world/category/Social+change))

I have consulted enough dictionaries to be fairly confident that this is not a dictionary usage. This is not to say "sit" is intransitive only. You of course can *sit a child on your lap* or *sit your friend down*. But it seems really rare that *someone is sat there*. Is it regional?

Comment: `seated` is definitely correct. ie: "Sean is/was seated on a bus."  I am of the personal opinion that `sat` is improper, but it is a common acceptable usage, nonetheless.  You may want to take a look at the Q&A on this topic at English Lang & Usage : [Is “I am sat” bad English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18609/is-i-am-sat-bad-english).

Comment: @Nmath My question has been sufficiently answered. Thank you.

Comment: *Is sat* is seen more in UK English than in US English. It's both colloquial (and not widely used) and something that used to be more common in the past than it is now.